# Error: I can't visit the site when run the cypress e2e tests inside my docker container -add-host

Tags: docker, cypress, e2e-testing, host

I have two container, the first is with my dev project and the second is with my cypress e2e tests, so, I have the next configuration to run the conatiner with my tests, where I do reference to my dev container

```
docker run -ti --rm \
   -v ${PWD}:/app \
   -v root_cache:/root/.cache \
   --add-host=widehire.dev:host-gateway \
   --env CYPRESS_ROOT_URL=http://widehire.dev:4000 \
   --env ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 \
   --workdir /app \
   cypress/base:17.8.0 \
   bash
```

I run the container and run the command yarn test:e2e to run my tests inside the container, but, it looks like a cycle because I have a console.log inside my tests to view the ROOT_URL and always is printed every few seconds, this is the log

```
    [454:0731/201931.961334:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: http://localhost:59329/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/201940.701859:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/201947.831196:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/201952.685721:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/201955.881990:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202003.027272:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202008.779334:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202011.647769:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202013.880118:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202015.921544:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
[454:0731/202018.270232:INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "http://widehire.dev:4000", source: https://widehire.dev:4000/__cypress/tests?p=widehire-app/web-app/cypress/e2e/landing-page.cy.ts (107)
```

It never flows with the next lines, here is the test's code

```
 it('should load the header successfully', () => {
    console.log(Cypress.env('ROOT_URL'))
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('ROOT_URL'));
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .ant-btn > span').should(
      'have.text',
      'Clients Login'
    );
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .ant-btn > span').should(
      'have.text',
      'Consultants Login'
    );
    cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .ant-btn > span').should('have.text', 'Console');
  });
```

but if I do 'curl [http://widehire.dev:4000'](http://widehire.dev:4000%27)  I can see the source code in the page in the console

and, inside the dev container, the console shows that logs when run the tests in the other container

```
    (RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 346.867 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 98.074 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 131.261 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 159.373 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 270.762 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 301.227 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 155.560 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 243.502 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 344.536 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 201.117 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 194.131 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 204.594 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 102.028 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 98.692 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 109.770 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 155.188 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 155.911 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 142.526 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 295.163 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 158.271 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 185.359 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 144.565 ms
(RUN) @widehire-app/server: GET / 200 - - 159.153 ms
```

So, I don't whats is happend, somebody can help me?